# AHRS Algorithm Question

Tags: quadcopter

As far as i understand, AHRS use orientation reference vectors to detect orientation error. And we can use magnetometer to correct yaw drift. But i see from my ak895 magnetometer that the data is not so stable, it kind of fluctuates continuously.

How can we use this data for AHRS algorithm?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on your question. What do you mean with fluctuation? Normally magnetometers are quite stable, but have a large bias when getting close to other magnetic objects. Also, which AHRS algorithms have you tried so far? What was the result?

Comment: Direction cosine matrix. When magnetometer's is held flat on the table, the difference between max value of heading and min value can be up to 4-5 degree

Comment: Best to update your question. Also, how do the raw readings behave? You don't provide enough information at this point to answer your question.

Comment: the raw magnetomer's readings are also noisy. do you have to filter it out?

Comment: Haven't worked with DCM. But maybe you should try a complemantary or Kalman filter approach. Update your question with the details, and you may get an answer.

Comment: I used to try with complimentary filter. The problem is that roll and pitch are really good, but the yaw angle is not stable and noisy. So finally, i change to AHRS with DCM, which i saw that some quadcopters like arducopter is currently using!
Refer to adrucopter, i see that it used GPS as a reference for yaw, is it better than magnetometer?